# Android, splitting a .csv by line break?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, csv

Firstly, I'm crap at english. I hope it's okay;
*I have a small project to do: parsing a .csv file:*

**Typical .csv file**

```
The recording starts at 2014,Sep,9,4:40:24 PM
accX,accY,accZ,gX,gY,gZ,
-0.3958511,0.014643669,10.037987,-13.17548,-2.3169785,-3.2103431,
-0.29875562,0.014643669,10.037987,-53.558975,0.22515106,-36.11273,
-0.29875562,0.014643669,10.23412,-50.653694,0.7335739,-32.481117,
The recording ends at 2014,Sep,9,4:40:29 PM
```

I tried OPENcsv library but I couldn't make it work. So I find an explaination on stackOverFlow, and I used it, it works well. Initially, it split the file with commas "," and it works.

But I changed it to split it by line break, as you can see with line.split("\r?\n"). It doesn't work, it crash in fact.

**MainActivity.java**

```
File f = new File(path + "/" + "motionTracker/");        
            File f2 = new File(f + "/" + stringx);
try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(f2.toString());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // handle exception
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            String date = "kek";
            String value = "wow";
            String line = "lel";       
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     String[] RowData = line.split("\\r?\\n");
                     date = RowData[0];
                     value = RowData[1];
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                // handle exception
            }
            finally {
                try {
                   fis.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // handle exception
                }
            }
```

Do you think the problem is because there are no line break in a .csv file? 
Or maybe I did something wrong with my code.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can only split on a single char - could you possible split on the **comma** instead?

Comment: This is not a well-formed CSV file. In a well formed CSV file you don't have the "Recording Starts/Ends at" lines and you shoud have **line terminators** (i.e.: `\n`)

Comment: you can split with ANY String @jbutler483 one, two or hundred characters..

Comment: @MartinFrank i've actually only used it in NETMF, so it's good to know that full .Net can split like that :)

Comment: glad i could point that out - i use the split function very much so i'm quite firm at that .... @jbutler483

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use a

```
BufferedReader reader
```

and read your file line by line

```
line = reader.readLine()
```

then **your line doesn't contain a line break** ('\n' or '\r?\n')...

so what will happen?

```
String[] RowData = line.split("\\r?\\n");
```

the size of this array MUST ALWAYS be 1 and would be the same as the `String line`

so ultimately

```
 date = RowData[0]; // equal to line
 value = RowData[1]; //index out of bounds - line has never been splitted
```

an IndexOutOfBounds-Exception will be thrown here...

Comment: Are you telling me it's not possible to split it by line break? i'm kinda sad.

Comment: of course you can split by linebreak! 100% possible!!! but your line **DOES'NT HAVE A LINE BREAK** sorry...

Comment: the cool thing about readLine is the fact that you read the file line by line - and a line contains all text **but not the line break itself**....

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. But I understand that I have to parse the lines with lineparsed = reader.readLine(), which contains the line! It's great! Thank you very much, that's what I needed.

Comment: i'm glad i could help - i hope i was not too aggressive with my answers, because i really wish to help you!

Comment: but once you have your line: line = reader.readLine() then you can split again with "," ...